# Google agenda question (Still need help)

Tags: contacts, nexus-5, google, google-contacts, people-app

my question is more related to the Google contacts system than to Android itself, but hope you can help me.. I have a Nexus 5, and my agenda looks organized with everything that I added perfectly. The problem is when I go to the people section is shows me clones of my contacts for example: my girlfriend contact with phone number and another with the Skype name, but it's the same person. The problem is that when I try to merge both contacts to be perfect, it doesn't stay with my contact name but instead with the Skype name! For example, her name is Ana and her Skype name is Anaaa.. And when I merge them it appears now as Ana.. Not only in people but also in my contact list.. I tried to see in the settings to fix this, but can't find the solution.

Comment: That answer just fix half of the problem. It solves the clones contacts, but it doesn't solve if I want to add her Skype to my contact and keep her real name! Somehow this Google contacts seems to prioritize Skype name first and real name after.. Doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all Skype contacts in Contacts to display settings.